# compress a string in python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, zlib, compression

I don't understand
in 2.X it worked :

```
import zlib
zlib.compress('Hello, world')
```

now i have a :

```
zlib.compress("Hello world!")
TypeError: must be bytes or buffer, not str
```

How can i compress my string ?
Regards
Bussiere

Comment: Compression always works on sequences of bytes, but you need to convert to them first (i.e., pick an encoding for the characters as bytes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is meant to enforce that you actually have a defined encoding.

```
zlib.compress("Hello, world".encode("utf-8"))
b'x\x9c\xf3H\xcd\xc9\xc9\xd7Q(\xcf/\xcaI\x01\x00\x1b\xd4\x04i'
zlib.compress("Hello, world".encode("ascii"))
b'x\x9c\xf3H\xcd\xc9\xc9\xd7Q(\xcf/\xcaI\x01\x00\x1b\xd4\x04i'
```

The same string could describe different byte sequences otherwise. But it is actually a byte sequence that will be encoded by zlib.

```
>>> zlib.compress("Hello, wørld".encode("utf-16"))
b'x\x9c\xfb\xff\xcf\x83!\x95!\x07\x08\xf3\x19t\x18\x14\x18\xca\x19~0\x14\x01y)\x0c\x00n\xa6\x06\xef'
>>> zlib.compress("Hello, wørld".encode("utf-8"))
b"x\x9c\xf3H\xcd\xc9\xc9\xd7Q(?\xbc\xa3('\x05\x00#\x7f\x05u"
```

Comment: Curious: why does this work for me (Python 3.0.1, Ubuntu Jaunty) without calling `encode`?

Comment: Check the release docs, this change might be enforced in a later version of 3.

Comment: Wow, 2019 and this answer is still helpful.  Thanks for posting all those years ago.

Comment: You are welcome. Isn't it great if your basic implementation details don't change every few years. :D

Answer (score 19):

In python 2.x strings are bytes string by default. In python 3.x they are unicode strings.

Compressing needs a byte string.