# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, string, gzip

```python
plaintext = input("Please enter the text you want to compress")
filename = input("Please enter the desired filename")
with gzip.open(filename + ".gz", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(plaintext)
```

The above python code is giving me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ankur Gupta/Desktop/Python_works/gzip_work1.py", line 33, in <module>
    compress_string()
  File "C:/Users/Ankur Gupta/Desktop/Python_works/gzip_work1.py", line 15, in compress_string
    outfile.write(plaintext)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\gzip.py", line 312, in write
    self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffff
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 300, accepted):

If you use Python3x then `string` is not the same type as for Python 2.x, you must cast it to bytes (encode it).

```
plaintext = input("Please enter the text you want to compress")
filename = input("Please enter the desired filename")
with gzip.open(filename + ".gz", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(bytes(plaintext, 'UTF-8'))
```

Also do not use variable names like `string` or `file` while those are names of module or function.

*EDIT @Tom*

Yes, non-ASCII text is also compressed/decompressed. I use Polish letters with UTF-8 encoding:

```
plaintext = 'Polish text: ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ'
filename = 'foo.gz'
with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(bytes(plaintext, 'UTF-8'))
with gzip.open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    outfile_content = infile.read().decode('UTF-8')
print(outfile_content)
```

Comment: It's odd that this fixed it; the original code worked for me under 3.1, and the sample code in the docs also does not encode explicitly. If you use it on non-ASCII text, does gunzip decompress it? I got an error.

Comment: I typed my Name in Unicode Hindi and it compressed it in gzip successfully. I am using Python 3.2

Comment: @Tom Zych: Probably has something to do with the changes in 3.2: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#gzip-and-zipfile

Comment: I tested it with ActiveState Python 3.1 and 3.2. On my machine it works in both.

Comment: I was trying to do this: `gzip.write(input_file.read())`. The equivalent to calling `bytes(...)` in this case is to open the input file in binary mode: `input_file = open('filename', 'rb')`

Comment: For file compression you should **always** open the input in binary mode: You need to be able to uncompress the file later and get exactly the same content. Converting to Unicode (`str`) and back is unnecessary, and risks decoding errors or mismatches between input and output.

Comment: @alexis In this case it's about the `gzip.open()` method, not the Python `open()` function. I'm sure the gzip part opens the file in binary mode, the question is what type for the uncompressed text it presents to the rest of the program.

Answer (score 97):

There is an easier solution to this problem.

You just need to add a `t` to the mode so it becomes `wt`. This causes Python to open the file as a text file and not binary. Then everything will just work.

The complete program becomes this:

```python
plaintext = input("Please enter the text you want to compress")
filename = input("Please enter the desired filename")
with gzip.open(filename + ".gz", "wt") as outfile:
    outfile.write(plaintext)
```

Comment: Does it work on python2 too? Could it be a way to make the code work on python2 and python3?

Comment: Wow, man you are good! Thanks! Let me vote you up. This should be the accepted answer :))

Comment: Adding "t" can have side-effects.  On windows files encoded as text will have newlines ("\n") converted to CRLF ("\r\n").

Answer (score 43):

You can not serialize a Python 3 'string' to bytes without explict conversion to some encoding.

```python
outfile.write(plaintext.encode('utf-8'))
```

is possibly what you want. Also this works for both python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 28):

For Python 3.x you can convert your text to raw bytes through:

```
bytes("my data", "encoding")
```

For example:

```
bytes("attack at dawn", "utf-8")
```

The object returned will work with `outfile.write`.

Answer (score 10):

This problem commonly occurs when switching from py2 to py3. In py2 `plaintext` represented both a *string* and a *byte array* type, it was type flexible, able to swing both ways. In py3 `plaintext` is only a *string* now, it is more definite, and the method `outfile.write()` actually takes a *byte array* when `outfile` is opened in binary mode, so an exception is raised. Change the input to `plaintext.encode('utf-8')` to fix the problem. Read on if this bothers you.

In py2, the [declaration for file.write](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) made it seem like you passed in a string: `file.write(str)`. Actually you were passing in a byte array, you should have been reading the declaration like this: `file.write(bytes)`. If you read it like this the problem is simple, `file.write(bytes)` needs a *bytes* type and in py3 to get *bytes* out of a *str* you convert it:

```
py3>> outfile.write(plaintext.encode('utf-8'))
```

Why did the py2 docs declare `file.write` took a string? Well in py2 the declaration distinction didn't matter because:

```
py2>> str==bytes         #str and bytes aliased a single hybrid class in py2
True
```

The *str-bytes* class of py2 has methods/constructors that make it behave like a string class in some ways and a byte array class in others. Convenient for `file.write` isn't it?:

```
py2>> plaintext='my string literal'
py2>> type(plaintext)
str                              #is it a string or is it a byte array? it's both!

py2>> outfile.write(plaintext)   #can use plaintext as a byte array
```

Why did py3 break this nice system? Well because in py2 basic string functions didn't work for the rest of the world. Measure the length of a word with a non-ASCII character?

```
py2>> len('¡no')        #length of string=3, length of UTF-8 byte array=4, since with variable len encoding the non-ASCII chars = 2-6 bytes
4                       #always gives bytes.len not str.len
```

All this time you thought you were asking for the *len* of a string in py2, you were getting the length of the byte array from the encoding. That ambiguity is the fundamental problem with double-duty classes. Which version of any method call do you implement?

The good news then is that py3 fixes this problem. It disentangles the *str* and *bytes* classes. The *str* class has string-like methods, the separate *bytes* class has byte array methods:

```
py3>> len('¡ok')       #string
3
py3>> len('¡ok'.encode('utf-8'))     #bytes
4
```

Hopefully knowing this helps de-mystify the issue, and makes the migration pain a little easier to bear.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = bytes("s","utf-8")
>>> print(s)
b's'
>>> s = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> print(s)
s
```

Well if useful for you in case removing annoying 'b' character.If anyone got better idea please suggest me or feel free to edit me anytime in here.I'm just newbie

Comment: You can also use `s.encode('utf-8')` it so pythonic as `s.decode('utf-8')` in replacement of `s = bytes("s", "utf-8")`

Answer (score 4):

For `Django` in `django.test.TestCase` unit testing, I changed my **Python2** syntax:

```
def test_view(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('myview'))
    self.assertIn(str(self.obj.id), response.content)
    ...
```

To use the **Python3** `.decode('utf8')` syntax:

```
def test_view(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('myview'))
    self.assertIn(str(self.obj.id), response.content.decode('utf8'))
    ...
```