# Should I trust "python -3" as returning an exhaustive result?

Tags: python, compatibility

As you can read in "man python" :

> -3     Warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix.

This command allready help me in the past to avoid incompatibility between
code for Python 2.x & 3.x.

However, i don't have any warning for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233786/overriding-bool-for-custom-class) code.
Should I trust "python -3" as returning an exhaustive result ?

NB : Surprinsigly, there is no mention of this option [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#using-on-general).

Comment: Because that code isn't incompatible with 3.x. Unless you mean using `__nonzero__`? In which case, it's probably because it's looking for "incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot **trivially** fix" and that's a pretty trivial fix. It's unclear what code you're talking about.

Comment: Your link goes to the Python 3 documentation. Python 3 doesn't have that flag. (Surprisingly, the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-3) doesn't mention the 2to3 caveat.)

Comment: @user2357112 -- Yeah, I'm surprised by that too (which is why my initial answer had code that 2to3 handles trivially).

Comment: I've added a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue27470) against the documentation.  Who knows how long it will be before they fix it (or if they do)... But at least it's there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not treat that warning as exhaustive.  The following code behaves differently on python2.x and python3.x but emits no warnings:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class test(object):
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False

t = test()
if t:
    print('Hello')
```

(at least not as of python2.7.10 on OSX).  Ok, perhaps this code can be handled by 2to3 (it is) -- though I would still expect a warning based on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-3).

> Warn about Python 3.x possible incompatibilities by emitting a DeprecationWarning for features that are removed or significantly changed in Python 3.

Here's an example of some code that [*isn't* handled by 2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965874/python-3-writing-to-a-pipe) but still no warning is emitted using the `-3` option:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess

class Pipe(object):
    def __init__(self,openstr):
        self.gnu_process=subprocess.Popen(openstr.split(),
                                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    def put_in_pipe(self,mystr):
        print(mystr, file=self.gnu_process.stdin)

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("This simple program just echoes what you say (control-d to exit)")
    p = Pipe("cat -")
    while True:
        try:
            inpt = raw_input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        print('putting in pipe:%s' % inpt)
        p.put_in_pipe(inpt)
```

The problem with this code is that in python3, my pipe expects a bytes object but it's getting a `str` (python2.x's unicode).