# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, file-io, md5

```python
import hashlib

infile = open("P:\\r.mp3", 'r+b')
data = infile.readline()
hash = hashlib.md5()
hash.update(data)

hash_digest = hash.hexdigest()
print(hash_digest)
#hash_digest = hash_digest.encode('utf-8')
print(hash_digest)
with open("lt.txt", 'ab') as outfile:
    outfile.write(hash_digest + '\n')   #error here

with open("syncDB.txt", 'rb') as fg:
    for data in fg:
    print(data)
```

```
outfile.write(hash_digest + '\n')
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

How do I correct that and what do I need to learn to see me through these situations?

Also if I encode this in utf-8(uncomment) it gives out the following error:

```
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're using Python 3, where there is a strict division between text (`str`) and data (`bytes`). Text can't be written to a file if you don't explicitly encode it first.

There are two ways to do this:

1) Open the file in text mode (possibly with an encoding specified) so that strings are automatically encoded for you:

```python
with open("lt.txt", 'at', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(hash_digest + '\n') # or print(hash_digest, file=outfile)
```

If you don't specify the encoding yourself when opening the file in text mode, the default encoding of your system locale would be used.

2) Encode the strings manually like you tried. But don't try to mix `str` with `bytes` like you did, either use a byte literal:

```python
hash_digest = hash_digest.encode('utf-8')
with open("lt.txt", 'ab') as outfile:
    outfile.write(hash_digest + b'\n')   # note the b for bytes
```

or encode after adding the newline:

```python
    outfile.write((hash_digest + '\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: You don't need to call f.close() if you're using with-open-as.  (Of course I realize you were simply matching the OP's code.)

Comment: Thanks ! I had problem with `csv.writer` , `writer.writerow` with same error. I've encountered problems adter switching from sys.stdout to file `open()`. Your solution solved my problems :).

Answer (score -5):

You must search in Google for **'str' does not support the buffer interface**

You'll have plenty of answers like this one:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

And for the second error **TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
** , I think you must write `b'\n'` in `f.write(hex + '\n')`

""" edit

yes Rosh Oxymoron is right, b'\n' , and not u'\n'