# Web scraping urlopen in python

Tags: python, urlopen

I am trying to get the data from this website:
http://www.boursorama.com/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS

It seems like urlopen don't get the html code and I don't understand why.
It goes like:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.boursorama.com/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS")
print (html)
```

My code is right, I get the html source of other webpages with the same code, but it seems like it doesn't recognise this address.

it prints: b''

Maybe another library is more appropriate? Why urlopen doesn't return the html code of the webpage?
help thanks!

Comment: Searching threads on web connexions subject on SO would have give you a lot of information. But that's not a serious fault for a new user, anyway. So I upvoted YOU, not the question, to welcome you on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally , I write:

```
# Python 2.7

import urllib

url = 'http://www.boursorama.com/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS'
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
content = sock.read() 
sock.close()

print content
```

Et si tu parles français,.. bonjour sur stackoverflow.com !

#### update 1

In fact, I prefer now to employ the following code, because it is faster:

```
# Python 2.7

import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host='www.boursorama.com',timeout=30)

req = '/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS'

try:
    conn.request('GET',req)
except:
     print 'echec de connexion'

content = conn.getresponse().read()

print content
```

Changing `httplib` to `http.client` in this code should be enough to adapt it to Python 3.

.

I confirm that, with these two codes, I obtain the source code in which I see the data in which you are interested:

```
        <td class="L20" width="33%" align="center">11:57:44</td>

        <td class="L20" width="33%" align="center">1.4486</td>

        <td class="L20" width="33%" align="center">0</td>

</tr>

                                        <tr>

        <td  width="33%" align="center">11:57:43</td>

        <td  width="33%" align="center">1.4486</td>

        <td  width="33%" align="center">0</td>

</tr>
```

#### update 2

Adding the following snippet to the above code will allow you to extract the data I suppose you want:

```
for i,line in enumerate(content.splitlines(True)):
    print str(i)+' '+repr(line)

print '\n\n'


import re

regx = re.compile('\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="(?:gras )?L20" width="33%" align="center">(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)</td>\r\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="(?:gras )?L20" width="33%" align="center">([\d.]+)</td>\r\n'
                  '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="(?:gras )?L20" width="33%" align="center">(\d+)</td>\r\n')

print regx.findall(content)
```

result (only the end)

```
.......................................
.......................................
.......................................
.......................................
98 'window.config.graphics = {};\n'
99 'window.config.accordions = {};\n'
100 '\n'
101 "window.addEvent('domready', function(){\n"
102 '});\n'
103 '</script>\n'
104 '<script type="text/javascript">\n'
105 '\t\t\t\tsas_tmstp = Math.round(Math.random()*10000000000);\n'
106 '\t\t\t\tsas_pageid = "177/(includes/cours/last_transactions)"; // Page : boursorama.com/smartad_test\n'
107 '\t\t\t\tvar sas_formatids = "8968";\n'
108 '\t\t\t\tsas_target = "symb=1xEURUS#"; // TargetingArray\n'
109 '\t\t\t\tdocument.write("<scr"+"ipt src=\\"http://ads.boursorama.com/call2/pubjall/" + sas_pageid + "/" + sas_formatids + "/" + sas_tmstp + "/" + escape(sas_target) + "?\\"></scr"+"ipt>");\t\t\t\t\n'
110 '\t\t\t</script><div id="_smart1"><script language="javascript">sas_script(1,8968);</script></div><script type="text/javascript">\r\n'
111 "\twindow.addEvent('domready', function(){\r\n"
112 'sas_move(1,8968);\t});\r\n'
113 '</script>\n'
114 '<script type="text/javascript">\n'
115 'var _gaq = _gaq || [];\n'
116 "_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1623710-1']);\n"
117 "_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.boursorama.com']);\n"
118 "_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'segment', 'WEB-VISITOR']);\n"
119 "_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'version', '18']);\n"
120 "_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);\n"
121 "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);\n"
122 '(function() {\n'
123 "var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;\n"
124 "ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';\n"
125 "var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\n"
126 '})();\n'
127 '</script>\n'
128 '</body>\n'
129 '</html>'



[('12:25:36', '1.4478', '0'), ('12:25:33', '1.4478', '0'), ('12:25:31', '1.4478', '0'), ('12:25:30', '1.4478', '0'), ('12:25:30', '1.4478', '0'), ('12:25:29', '1.4478', '0')]
```

I hope you don't plan to "play" trading on the Forex: it's one of the best way to loose money rapidly.

### update 3

SORRY ! I forgot you are with Python 3. So I think you must define the regex like that:

> regx = re.compile(**b**'\t\t\t\t\t......)

that is to say with **b** before the string, otherwise you'll get an error like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139225/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Comment: Merci, I won't be able to test the code until tonight. Are you sure that you get the html source code with it?
And yes, I am on python 3 ;-)

Comment: @Kingpin Yes, I get it, I rarely post codes that I didn't test. But I'm using Python 2.7. I then understood that you are with Python 3, seeing ``print(html)`` with parens, but  I didn't try Python 3 enough to know that my code would fail in Python 3. Sorry

Comment: httplib doesn't exist in Python 3, and I'd suggest not using regex for something that you should handle with a parser (BeautifulSoup et al).

Comment: @Robert S. We know, we know. It's tiring to have always this same reaction when someone use regexes to extract data from HTML source code. The snippet works and I wrote it in 2 minutes. Are you ready to help _Kingpin_ learning BeautifulSoup during 1 or 2 hours ? By the way, BS is 10 times slower than a pure regex app.

Comment: @euquem Fair enough -- I just think that he should be told that it's not always a good idea. Using a library means that you don't have to hand-code regexes, which in turn leaves your code more robust (and more readable), and you won't have to fix a bug every time bad HTML breaks your regex. But I see your point; at times you can use regexes.

Comment: @Robert S. I agree: _not always a good way_. But it's better for the person to know why and when. It's essentially parsing _stricto sensu_ that is not possible with regexes; but here, he doesn't want to parse, he just want to analyze and find a particular and limited portion of the source code. - On the point of fixing bugs frequently, that's not the case when it's always the same portion of a source code that is analyzed, it's what I believe, maybe am I wrong ? - By the way, I particularly love regexes, so it's not a problem for me to craft a regex's pattern.

Answer (score 4):

What I suspect is happening is that the server is sending compressed data without telling you that it's doing so. Python's standard HTTP library can't handle compressed formats.
I suggest getting httplib2, which can handle compressed formats (and is generally much better than urllib).

```
import httplib2
folder = httplib2.Http('.cache')
response, content = folder.request("http://www.boursorama.com/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS")
```

`print(response)` shows us the response from the server:
{'status': '200', 'content-length': '7787', 'x-sid': '26,E', 'content-language': 'fr', 'set-cookie': 'PHPSESSIONID=ed45f761542752317963ab4762ec604f; path=/; domain=.www.boursorama.com', 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent', 'server': 'nginx', 'connection': 'keep-alive', **'-content-encoding': 'gzip'**, 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'date': 'Tue, 23 Aug 2011 10:26:46 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1', 'content-location': 'http://www.boursorama.com/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS'}

While this doesn't confirm that it was zipped (we're now telling the server that we can handle compressions, after all), it does lend some weight to the theory.

The actual content lives in, you guessed it, `content`. Looking at it briefly shows us that it's working (I'm just gonna paste a wee bit):
`b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"\n\t"http://`

**Edit**: yes, this does create a folder named .cache; I've found that it's always better to work with folders when it comes to httplib2, and you can always delete the folder afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your URL with the [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) and on the terminal with curl. Both work fine:

```
URL = "http://www.boursorama.com/includes/cours/last_transactions.phtml?symbole=1xEURUS"
h = httplib2.Http()
resp, content = h.request(URL, "GET")
print(content)
```

So to me, either there is a bug in urllib.request or there is really weird client-server interaction happening.

Comment: It was a typo, My real code include the "" to make it a string..
It doesn't work.
My question is a real question

Comment: @jazz it's probably the server that's sending the data compressed, urllib is a bit limited.

Comment: @Robert: Unfortunately not; the response is empty and in Python 2 it works also fine. It must be specific to Python 3 and urllib.request.

Comment: @jazz but `Content-length` is 7787 on `response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`, which would indicate that something gets sent along other than mere headers -- looking at it with online tools show the same content length but the actual source code as well, implying that it's not an empty response. So yeah, there's something weird going on with urllib.request.