# Can't get urlopen in Python 2.7 to work

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, httplib

I'm trying to follow the suggestions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158353/web-scraping-urlopen-in-python), but its not working.  At this point, I just wanted to perform a very simple test to make sure that I was actually getting the data returned from the site I'm trying to open.  For my simple test I was trying to open the Yahoo weather api.  I've verified that typing in this address in a web browser does indeed return data.  I've tried both of these code snippets and neither one is working.

```
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({'w': 2482950})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?%s" % params)
print f.read()
```

This example came straight from the Python website.  This dies with:

> IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out

I also tried using httplib like this:

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host='weather.yahooapis.com', timeout=10)
req = '/forecastrss?w=2482950'
try:
    conn.request('GET',req)
except:
    print "Didn't work"

content = conn.getresponse().read()
print content
```

Trying this gives me the following error:

```
  self.fp = sock.makefile('rb', 0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'makefile'
```

It appears that I'm not ever making the connection to the remote host.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Both examples work for me.

Comment: Does your computer have a firewall enabled? If so, does it allow network connections made by the Python executable?

Comment: There is a firewall, but other folks that I work with have used Python to make network connections.  But now that I think about it, they were connecting to internal websites... so maybe that is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the firewall.  I added the following code to get it to work:

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://<proxy>:<port>"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print html
```