# SSL Socket Communication in CGI a good idea?

Tags: linux, apache, cgi

I would like there be a way to communicate between and Apache Server and an Application running on a Linux laptop.

The only way I can think of doing this is using SSL Sockets in a  CGI  python or perl script. Is this a good idea by any chance?

The Apache Server and the application are on the same machine, so perhaps having encryption might not be a big deal, since an attacker would need to gain physical access to hack the process. On the other hand it is connected to the network, and possibly could be sniffed.

Is encryption in such a case? Could an attacker sniff the data in that case?

Also if this is indeed a good idea, does anyone have resources on how to implement ssl socket with perl or python?

Comment: If you are using loop back address (local host or 127.0.0.1), i don't think it can be sniffed on the network since it doesn't go beyond your interface card. So encryption is not a concern here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using loop back address (local host or 127.0.0.1), i don't think it can be sniffed on the network since it doesn't go beyond your interface card. So encryption is not a concern here.

For the second part, following is an [SO example python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/very-basic-python-client-socket-example) though uou can find tons any way.

Another thing is being on Linux, you can simply connect via shell too. Just use netcat i.e. [nc](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/netcat). You can send any text to server as well as read back using this command line application.

Don't reinvent the wheel.