# Listening to port and capturing data in python

Tags: python

I am using an application in C which sends continous data to a specified port. I can view the incoming data using 'Putty' (with telnet 127.0.0.1 port 30003).

Now I want to capture that data for processing. Please advice how to do that in python?

The data flows in line by line, at a rate of 5 lines per second. I should read the data line by line for processing and display it in a window.

Comment: Your application is in`C` or in `python`?

Comment: you need to use socket programming

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like homework... You haven't tried to do it.

In python, to receive and send data (and definitely exchange data), we use the library called `socket`. You need two scripts, a server-side (which you've written in C) and a client-side script.

```
# client example

import socket, time
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 5000))
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    data = client_socket.recv(512)
    if data.lower() == 'q':
        client_socket.close()
        break

    print("RECEIVED: %s" % data)
    data = input("SEND( TYPE q or Q to Quit):")
    client_socket.send(data)
    if data.lower() == 'q':
        client_socket.close()
        break
```

This is a client-side script example, which receives the data each 5 secs and prints it out. I hope you can adapt it to fit your needs.

Source: [Basic Python client socket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/very-basic-python-client-socket-example)

Comment: Hai, sorry for not giving a try. Actually I tried several opions but failed. Your codes works perfectly. Can I ask a qustion? As I mentioned the data flow is not continous, it is silent for some time, then comes like that. So is there an option other than a loop so that data is recieved when it comes rather than checking it in every 5 seconds?? Thanks

Comment: @ManojPJoseph maybe avoiding that loop but always using a loop. A server is always checking if there are any incoming connections. A infinite loop works just fine, a lot of things work that way. I also sometimes try to avoid them but you will always have to do some of the kind (I speak from my experience, there may be something I do not know).

Answer (score 3):

Install tcpflow

Run the given script

```
import os

INTERFACE = "lo"

PORT = "30003"

os.system("tcpflow -i %s port %s" % (INTERFACE, PORT))
```

It will write the requests which are coming to the port into a file like 127.000.000.001.06080-127.000.000.001.6347 in script's location

Comment: He says `capture the data for processing``

Comment: I finally wrote the program to recieve data through a socket:                                         from socket import *

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 30003    #our port from before
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096

sock = socket( AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ADDR))

def readlines(sock, recv_buffer=4096, delim='\n'):
 buffer = ''
 data = True
 while data:
  data = sock.recv(recv_buffer)
  buffer += data
  
  while buffer.find(delim) != -1:
   line, buffer = buffer.split('\n', 1)
   yield line
   
 return
    
for line in readlines(sock):
 print line