# Find ips listening on a port with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-sockets

How can python help accept a specific port number from a user as input and return all the ips listening on that port on the system. The python script could be running locally on a linux system where this is needed or may access the linux system remotely using an ip specified and needs to get the ip listening on a particular port say. 9223.

Basically it should be similar to a python implementation of ***netstat -ln | grep port*** with port being a user input.

Would appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), to run a command line command like netstat.

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_output(['ls','-lah'])
```

To listen to ports, with Python code, I would refer to this topic

[Listening to port and capturing data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658634/listening-to-port-and-capturing-data-in-python)

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to get this done without the need to execute linux commands for getting this i.e. to using python socket programming library.