# Python socket programming-saving data from socket

Tags: python, sockets

I want to save bitstream data from a device connected to the ethernet port of my laptop.The ip address of the device is 192.168.2.100, telnet port 23. I have to read and store the data using python sockets.Can anyone please help me for this?

Comment: You want to know how to read a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/very-basic-python-client-socket-example) regarding connecting a socket and reading from it. Then it's a simple matter of opening a file and writing to it:

```
open("output.dat", "a").write(data)
```

The first parameter to 'open' is the file name, the second parameter is the mode (e.g. write, append, et cetera); the method called within the returned object 'write' has a parameter of the data you wish to write. As one statement, the file closes automatically. Otherwise you will want to close it with `close()` to ensure the cache is flushed to the disk, and the file handle is discarded properly.