# How to communicate that a job is done between core and client computers?

Tags: python, networking, communication, grid-computing

I essentially have two pythons scripts running on two local computers (one on each computer) that need to communicate when each of their jobs are done so the other script/computer can continue its job.

To be more specific I need to let one computer know when a file is done copying to the other so it can run a command on said file.

I know little to nothing about networks, but would the correct way to implement this a socket? If not what is?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its a simple client-server code you need to have between these two computers

This will help
[(Very) basic Python client socket example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749341/very-basic-python-client-socket-example)

now the question is which is client and which is server. This is better answered based on the design of the system. There may be multiple areas where these two need to be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Appreciate it!