# Socket didn't make connection with server

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Please help me in this code. Error is given below.

> Error: socket succesfully created 111 connection failed traceback most recent call last file custom-iec.py line 27 in module s.sendstartdt typeerror send argument 1 must be string buffer list

```
import socket 
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
a = socket.connect_ex(('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 2500))
#s = socket.socket()
port=2500
a=socket.connect_ex(('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', port))
print a
Packet = [

    0x68,
    0x04, 
    0x43,
    0x00, 
    0x00, 
    0x00 
    ]
socket.send(Packet)
print s.recv(256)
s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not overwrite the library function socket with your own socket variable. You may encounter problems when doing that.

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
^^ - better is: s = socket...
```

But i would recomment that you have a look @ this comment:

> ```
> import socket
>
> clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
> clientsocket.connect(('YOURIP', YOURPORT))   
> clientsocket.send('hello')
> ```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297623/8619512

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.X version, And in this version I should use coonect_ex() function. When I used this function connect(), it gave me an error.

Comment: and you're sending a only string there in function send('hello'). I think, I'm sending a variable which hold some value.

Answer (score 0):

> typeerror send argument 1 must be string buffer list

The correct wording of the error message is:

```
TypeError: send() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not list
```

And this says it - with `Packet = […` you defined a *list*, while `send()` expects a *string* or a *buffer*. You can define your packet as a string with `Packet = "\x68\x04\x43\x00\x00\x00"`.

Comment: How I define packet as a string. Could you please help me??

Comment: @Praveen Soni - _How I define packet as a string_: I wrote exactly how to do that.