# line contains NULL byte error in python csv reader

Tags: python, csv, null

I am trying to read each line of a csv file and get a "line contains NULL byte" error.

```
reader = csv.reader(open(mycsv, 'rU'))
for line in reader:
     print(line)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Using the below I found that I have null bytes.

```
if '\0' in open(mycsv).read():
     print("have null byte")
```

What's the best way to work around this? Do a replace '\0' on all lines? I need to process this kind of file daily and have about 400,000 lines (1Gb) of data. I assume a replace would substantially slow this down even more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this!

```py
import csv 

def mycsv_reader(csv_reader): 
  while True: 
    try: 
      yield next(csv_reader) 
    except csv.Error: 
      # error handling what you want.
      pass
    continue 
  return

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    reader = mycsv_reader(csv.reader(open(mycsv, 'rU')))
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

Comment: That works and gets me through the file, I am just wondering why I am getting these null bytes. Are they maybe used instead of commas as separators?
f.count('\x00')
returns 1926 of these.

Comment: Please refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python