# Django, reading csv from form request throws: Error: line contains NULL byte

Tags: python, django, csv

I have simple application written in django with one form that uploads `CSV`file.

My CSV file has a lot of columns with **cyrillic letters**. Just for testing I made my view handle html form like this:

```
@login_required()
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def upload_csv(request):

    uploaded_file = request.FILES['csv'].read(200)
    data = csv.reader(uploaded_file)
    for row in data:
        print(row)

    return redirect('moderator:upload_view')
```

When I try to upload my CSV, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py", line 42, in inner
return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "D:\myapp\moderator\views\upload.py", line 32, in upload_csv
for row in data:
Error: line contains NULL byte
[08/Apr/2017 13:53:41] "POST /moderator/upload_csv/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87052
```

First I thought that my CSV is corrupted. Then why other CSV readers and Excel can open it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this answer ["Line contains NULL byte" in CSV reader (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

which utilizes the [codecs library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html):

> ```
> import codecs
> csvReader = csv.reader(codecs.open('file.csv', 'rU', 'utf-16'))
> ```

to open the file with different encodings (ex: utf-16)

Good luck :)

Comment: I have made like this: `csvReader = csv.reader(codecs.open(uploaded_file, 'rU', 'utf-16'))` which throws me `TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str`

Comment: In the linked answer, there is the second most voted answer, which gives another solution (manipulating your CSV). You may want to try it as well!