# IndexError: list index out of range is thrown now that i've changed the way the file is read

Tags: python, csv, utf-16, index-error

I am trying to read and reformat a very large (2GB+) .out file that is structured like a csv. I had previously used the standard open(), with no such issue, but changed it to codecs.open() as it was having trouble with some characters.

It is now throwing

`Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 21, in <module>
    if(r[5]==""):
IndexError: list index out of range` on the first row, although there is definitely an element at r[5].
(runtime is 0.301s)

```python
import sys
import csv
import datetime
import codecs
maxInt=sys.maxsize
decrement=True

while decrement:
    decrement=False
    try:
        csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
    except OverflowError:
        maxInt = int(maxInt/10)
        decrement = True

with codecs.open("file.out", 'rU', 'utf-16-be') as source:
    rdr = csv.reader(source)
    with open("out.csv","w", newline='') as result:
        wtr = csv.writer(result)
        wtr.writerow(("Column1", "column2", "column3", "etc..."))
        for r in rdr:
            if(r[5]==""):
                continue
            wtr.writerow((datetime.datetime.strptime(r[5], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), r[3], r[7], r[9]+r[10]+" "+r[12]))
```

using utf-8 throws `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 12: invalid continuation byte`

using latin-1 or ISO-8859-1 throws `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 57-58: character maps to <undefined>`, albeit after running much more.

input file looks like this:

```
"A00017","K","G","1999","4530","01/12/1999","","","","PEOPLE TO ELECT MANGINELLI","","","","258 MAGNIOLIA DRIVE","SELDEN","NY","11784","","","404.57","","","","","","","2","","NAA","07/22/1999 08:43:59"
"A00037","K","G","1999","999999","01/12/1999","","","","CITIZENS TO ELECT TEDISCO TO ASSEMBLY","","","","","","","","","","0","","","","","","","2","","",""
"A00037","K","N","1999","1693","01/15/1999","","","","OUTSTANDING LOAN","","","","2176 GUILDERLAND AVE","SCHENECTADY","NY","12306","","","10474.8","10474.8","","","OTHER","","PREVIOUS LOAN FROM JAMES TEDISCO","","P","JM","07/15/1999 15:08:17"
"A00037","J","N","2000","1694","01/13/2000","","","","OUTSTANDING LOAN","","","","2176 GUILDERLAND","SCHENECTADY","NY","12306","","","10474.8","10474.8","","","OTHER","","LOANS FROM PREVIOUS CAMPAIGNS FROM J","","P","JM","01/14/1900 16:35:09"
"A00037","K","X","2000","999999","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","07/20/2000 00:00:00"
"A00037","J","X","2001","999999","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","01/17/2001 00:00:00"
"A00037","K","X","2002","999999","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","07/19/2002 00:00:00"
"A00037","J","X","2003","999999","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","01/21/2003 00:00:00"
"A00037","K","X","2003","999999","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","07/16/2003 00:00:00"
"A00037","J","X","2004","999999","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","01/22/2004 00:00:00"
```

i've gotten this far thanks to:

["Line contains NULL byte" in CSV reader (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python)

[_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063936/csv-error-field-larger-than-field-limit-131072)

Comment: can you print `r` in your loop?

Comment: Without seeing a file that reproduces the problem, it is extremely hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'file.out' which you are reading from, find out the separating character between the elements of each cell of a row. Like a '\t'-tab or ','-comma and pass it to the 'delimiter' attribute.

Try printing 'r' and see the character between the column names or the values in a row

```
rdr = csv.reader(source,delimiter=<separator>)
```

Comment: Did u try printing 'r' and see if it is an array?

Comment: tried printing r to console and got `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-97: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: use 'utf-8'  in   codecs.open("file.out", 'rU', 'utf-8')

Comment: Can you try using 'latin-1'  or 'ISO-8859-1'encoding instead of 'utf-8'

Comment: Can you try this code : rdr = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in source),delimiter=',')   Also can you share the line in the data which is causing error

Comment: I removed the line causing the NULL error. I now get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 57-58: character maps to <undefined>`