# Skip line in .txt import to postgresql

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm trying to import 5'000 .txt files into a postgresql database. My script is running fine as long as it doesn't reach a line which doesn't fit the format. For example every file has a new line at the end which also causes the script to crash.

I've tried to handle exceptions but to no success...

My script:

```
import csv
import os
import sys

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="demo",
    user="demo",
    password="123",
    port="5432"
)

cur = conn.cursor()

maxInt = sys.maxsize

while True:
    try:
        csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
        break
    except OverflowError:
        maxInt = int(maxInt / 10)


def searchFiles(directory='', extension=''):
    print('SEARCHING IN: ', directory)
    filelist = []
    extension = extension.lower()
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            if extension and name.lower().endswith(extension):
                filelist.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
            elif not extension:
                print('FAILED TO READ: ', (os.path.join(dirpath, name)))
    print('FINISHED FILE SEARCH AND FOUND ', str(len(filelist)), ' FILES')
    return filelist


def importData(fileToImport):
    with open(fileToImport, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':')

        for line in reader:
            try:
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO demo VALUES (%s, %s)""", (line[0], line[1]))
                conn.commit()
            except:
                pass
                print('FAILED AT LINE: ', line)


print(conn.get_dsn_parameters())
cur.execute("SELECT version();")
record = cur.fetchone()
print("You are connected to - ", record)

fileList = searchFiles('output', '.txt')

counter = 0
length = len(fileList)
for file in fileList:
    # if counter % 10 == 0:
    print('Processing File: ', str(file), ', COMPLETED: ', str(counter), '/', str(length))
    importData(str(file))
    counter += 1
print('FINISHED IMPORT OF ', str(length), ' FILES')
```

A few lines of the data I'm trying to import:

```
example1@example.com:123456
example2@example.com:password!1
```

The error I'm getting:

```
File "import.py", line 66, in <module>
    importData(str(file))
File "import.py", line 45, in importData
    for line in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

How should I handle lines which can not get imported?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback shows the source of the exception in `for line in reader`:

```
File "import.py", line 45, in importData
    for line in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

and you do not handle exceptions at that point. As the exception suggests, it is raised by your csv reader instance. While you certainly could wrap your for loop in a try-except block, your loop will still end once the exception raises.

This exception may be caused by the file having a different encoding than your locale's, which is assumed by [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) if no encoding is explicitly provided:

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is
>   platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to
>   get the current locale encoding.

The accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python) Q&A outlines a solution to deal with that, provided that you can identify the correct encoding to open the file with. The Q&A also shows some approaches on how to get rid of NULL bytes in the file, prior to handing it over to a reader.

You might also want to simply skip empty lines instead of firing them to your DB and handle the exception, e.g.

```
for line in reader:
    if not line:
        continue
    try:
        [...]
```