# Getting an error: Line Contains Null, Not sure the cause

Tags: python

I am getting and error: `line contains NUL`.  I think it means there's a strange character in my CSV file. But this program and import file worked on a different machine (both Macs), so I don't know if the cause is a different version of Python or how I am running it. From reading the other entries, I am thinking this line may also be the cause:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filePath, 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig", errors="ignore"))
```

Appreciate any help / advice!

```
paths CWD=/Users/sternit/Downloads/Ten-code-4, CPD=/Users/sternit/Downloads/Ten-code/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sternit/Downloads/Ten-code-4/Master.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/sternit/Downloads/Ten-code-4/Master.py", line 114, in main
    playerLists = loadFiles(CPD + "PlayerFiles/")
  File "/Users/sternit/Downloads/Ten-code-4/Master.py", line 50, in loadFiles
    for n, row in enumerate(reader):
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Line contains NULL byte" in CSV reader (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python)

Answer (score 2):

this should work fine:

```
data_initial = open(filePath, "rb")
data = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in data_initial), delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `csv` module says you have a "NULL" (silly message, should be "NUL") byte in your reading file, I would suggest checking out what is in your file.

Try use `rb`, it might make problem go away:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filePath, 'rb', encoding="utf-8-sig", errors="ignore"))
```

Depends on how the file generated, there might include NULL byte, so you might need to

1. Open it in an editor, to see whether it is a reasonable CSV file, if the file too big, use `nano` or [`head`](https://www.linuxhelp.com/head-tail-command) in CLI.
2. Using another library like pandas, which could be more robust.
3. If the problem persists, you can replace all the `'\x00',` with empty string:

```
fi = open(filePath, 'rb')
data = fi.read()
fi.close()
fo = open('mynew.csv', 'wb')
fo.write(data.replace('\x00', ''))
fo.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  Trying them now!

Comment: Best practice is to use a `with` statement for opening files, i.e. `with open(filePath, 'rb') as fi: data = fi.read()` and `with open('mynew.csv', 'wb') as fo: fo.write(data.replace('\x00', ''))`

Comment: @wjandrea, you are right on using `with`, but here is to open it up and save it, so I feel without using it would be fine. Thank for the suggestion.