# for row in reader: Error: line contains NUL

Tags: python

This is what my program looks like right now:

```
def getdata(file_name):
    with open(file_name, errors='ignore') as f:
        rowdata = []
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            rowdata.append(row)
    return rowdata
```

I keep getting this error

```
for row in reader:

Error: line contains NUL
```

Comment: Check if your csv file has any empty lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python

Comment: this error might even be caused if the encoding is different like `UTF-16` or something else

Comment: @rdas the problem is a NUL (`b'\x00'`) byte in the CSV, not an empty line.

Answer (score -2):

I am guessing you have a NULL value in the file. You can test that with

```
if '\0' in open('filename').read():
  print("you have null value in your file")
else:
  print("you don't")
```

if you do, replace null values with space.

```
reader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in filename)
```

then you can hopefully read file without error

Comment: This is a feasible workaround if you know what you are doing, but blindly replacing invalid data with different invalid data just to remove the symptom is a horrible approach.