# Python when reading csv file get error: _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, gzip

I keep receiving the following error message "csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
" when trying to read my gzip file contains NULLs at the header and end of file and I'm trying to figure out a way to skip these but cannot get past the error message. Has anyone come across this and has a solution?

```
from gzip import GzipFile
import csv
import codecs

gzipped = GzipFile(None, 'rb', fileobj=response['Body'])
lines = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(gzipped, 'utf-8'))
print (lines, "lines")

next(lines) #to skip header
```

Error: _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

I can't also use pandas lib as this lib is not available within the platform I am working on. Only basic python libs are available.

Comment: I think that might be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python

Comment: I have also tried using csv.reader( (line.replace('\0','') for line in l) ) but still end up with the same error

Comment: Are you sure it's UTF-8 encoded?