# Python _csv.Error: line contains NUL for a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I tried to print some records off "the file" in csv format, but it keeps showing the error in Title. Yes i tried to change encoding to utf8, utf-16, as well as utf-16-le using notepad++. it still doesn't work. Please help :c

This is the input code:

```
import csv
f=open("thefile.csv", 'r', encoding="ansi")
reader=csv.reader(f)
covaxin=0
covishield=0


c1="Covaxin"
c2="Covishield"
a="41 - 60 years"


for row in reader:
   if (row[3]==a):
      for bro in reader:
         if (bro[4]==c1):
            covaxin+=1
            print("Covaxin: ", covaxin)
         elif (bro[4]==c2):
            covishield+=1
            print("Covishield:", covishield)
         else:
            print("error")
         

f.close()
```

and this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Reader Program.py", line 13, in <module>
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the CSV file?

Answer (score 3):

The error message means that the cvs module is reading a NUL character from the file, i.e. a character with code 0. The most obvious reasons for that would be that the file actually contains such a character (which means that the file is broken), or that the file is encoded with a 16-bit encoding (such as UTF-16) but you are reading it with an 8-bit encoding (which would make every second character a NUL character, assuming the file keeps to the English alphabet). You must find out what encoding the file is in, and give the appropriate parameter to `open`. To check whether there is a NUL character even with the proper encoding chosen, you could read the entire file as a string and use Python's string manipulation functions to search for `'\u0000'` characters.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python) has several potentially useful code snippets and hints for looking at what's in the file.

Interestingly, it looks like this [error will be gone](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/28808) in a future version of Python.