# Why am i getting Traceback error on csv to text script which i used a python script that work on other work stations

Tags: python, windows, csv, text, scripting

I am getting the error below when I run the script. It works fine on a workstation. I am pretty new with python. What could be the problem? I am trying to convert all csv files in that directory to ascii text files. Any help will be appreciated on identifying the error and fixing the code.

Script

```
import os
import csv


def csv_to_txt(csv_file):
  """Converts a CSV file to a TXT file.

  Args:
    csv_file: The path to the CSV file.

  Returns:
    The path to the created TXT file.
  """
  txt_file = csv_file[:-4] + ".txt"


  with open(csv_file, "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with open(txt_file, "w") as txtfile:
      for row in reader:
        txtfile.write(", ".join(row) + "\n")

  return txt_file

def remove_old_txt_files(directory):
  """Removes all old CSV files from the specified directory.

  Args:
    directory: The directory to remove the CSV files from.
  """
  for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
      os.remove(os.path.join(directory, file))

def main():
  directory = "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps\TRENDMICRO_CSV_TO_TXT_SCRIPT\bin"

  # Remove all old TXT files.
  remove_old_txt_files(directory)

  # Convert all CSV files to TXT files.
  for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
      txt_file = csv_to_txt(os.path.join(directory, file))
      print("Converted {} to {}".format(file, txt_file))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Error

```
C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps\TRENDMICRO_CSV_TO_TXT_SCRIPT\bin>python convert_csv_to_txt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps\TRENDMICRO_CSV_TO_TXT_SCRIPT\bin\convert_csv_to_txt.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps\TRENDMICRO_CSV_TO_TXT_SCRIPT\bin\convert_csv_to_txt.py", line 44, in main
    txt_file = csv_to_txt(os.path.join(directory, file))
  File "C:\Program Files\SplunkUniversalForwarder\etc\apps\TRENDMICRO_CSV_TO_TXT_SCRIPT\bin\convert_csv_to_txt.py", line 20, in csv_to_txt
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

So the code works very well on my workstation but prints the error above on a windows 2019 server

Comment: Check this Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894856/line-contains-null-byte-in-csv-reader-python

Comment: Specify the encoding explicitly in the `open` calls.

Comment: I have specified the encoding and I am still getting the same error i mentioned earlier