# Error when using zlib.compress function in Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, zlib

I'm importing zlib in my Python program. It works fine in Python 2.6 but shows an error when I try to run it in Python 3.2.

This is my code:

```
import zlib
s = 'sam'
print ("Your string length is",len(s))
t = zlib.compress(s)
print ("Your compressed string is",t)
print ("Your compressed string length is",len(t))
print ("Your decompressed string is",zlib.decompress(t))
print ("Crc32 is",zlib.crc32(t))
```

The error I get is this:

```
Your string length is 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\workspace\samples\python\zip.py", line 4, in <module>
    t = zlib.compress(s)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

But the above program works fine in Python 2.6. Should I use an alternative to zlib? Please help me.

**Edit**: I got it to work. It seems I needed to encode it. Here is the revised code:

```
import zlib
s = 'sam'
print ("Your string length is",len(s))
s=s.encode('utf-8')
t = zlib.compress(s)
print ("Your compressed string is",t)
print ("Your compressed string length is",len(t))
print ("Your decompressed string is",zlib.decompress(t))
print ("Crc32 is",zlib.crc32(t))
```

Comment: The search on Stackoverflow *does* work: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=typeerror%3a%20%27str%27%20does%20not%20support%20the%20buffer%20interface

Comment: exact duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface) And two million other questions with the exact same error message and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Th `str` type in Python is no longer a sequence of 8-bit characters, but a sequence of Uncode characters. You need to use the `bytes` type for binary data. You convert between strings and bytes by encoding/decoding.