# Python 3 how to generate md5 hash from file on stdin?

Tags: python, string, buffer, md5

I am trying to calculate an md5 hash of a file from stdin using Python 3

Here is the error message returned.  I can't see why it doesn't return the md5 hash.  Any help appreciated.

```
$./pymd5.py < tmp.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pymd5.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "./pymd5.py", line 25, in main
    print(m.hexdigest())
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
$
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.2

import sys
import hashlib

BUFSIZE = 4096

def make_streams_binary():
    sys.stdin  = sys.stdin.detach()
    sys.stdout = sys.stdout.detach()

def main():
    make_streams_binary()
    m = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        data = sys.stdin.read(BUFSIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        m.update(data)

    print(m.hexdigest())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't really explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
sys.stdout = sys.stdout.detach()
```

It removes the ability to `print` normally at the terminal on Python 3, because you [get a buffer instead of one wrapped for encoding and decoding](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.detach). Before you `print`, you should do:

```
sys.stdout = sys._stdout
```

To get the original `stdout` back.