# Trying to get an image with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get an image from a website and I don't know what i am doing wrong. 
Here is my code:

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http('.cache')

response, content = h.request('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KSBzFF0bIyU/TtFyj-KgC0I/AAAAAAAABEo/o43IoY_9Bec/s1600/praia-de-ponta-verde-maceio.jpg')

print(response.status)

with open('maceio.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    print(content, file = f)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matheus/workspace/Get Link/new_method_v2.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(content, file = f)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the following line:

```
print(content, file = f)
```

`print` implicitely converts the `bytes` object named `content` to a string (`str` object), which cannot be written to a file in binary mode, since Python does not know which character encoding to use.

Why are you taking the `print` detour at all?  Just write the contents to the file using the `file.write()` method:

```
with open('maceio.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: Thank you!! If possible, can you talk a little more about the "g.write()" ?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write