# Writing to CSV with Python adds blank lines

Tags: python, csv, python-3.3

I am trying to write to CSV file but there are blank rows in between. How can I remove the blank rows?

```
import csv
b = open('test.csv', 'w')
a = csv.writer(b)
data = [['Me', 'You'],\
        ['293', '219'],\
        ['54', '13']]
a.writerows(data)
b.close()
```

Comment: You don't need backslashes at the end of the lines defining `data`.  Python ignores newlines inside the enclosing square brackets, i.e. between `[` and `]`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but that backslash is the continuation character, isnt it not?

Comment: This is old, but I noticed no one responded. The continuation character is not needed if you have a comma.

Comment: See also: [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41585078/562769)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The way you use the `csv` module changed in Python 3 in several respects [(docs)](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.writer), at least with respect to how you need to open the file.  Anyway, something like

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data = [['Me', 'You'],
            ['293', '219'],
            ['54', '13']]
    a.writerows(data)
```

should work.

Comment: ERROR: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function ?

Comment: @SaadBinShahid: then you're not using Python 3.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Python 2.x on Windows you need to change your line `open('test.csv', 'w')` to `open('test.csv', 'wb')`. That is you should open the file as a [binary file](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

However, as stated by others, the file interface has changed in Python 3.x.

Comment: is this caused by Windows automatically adding nl-characters when writing text instead of binary?

Comment: I tried by I get this error: w.writrows(data) 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: I am using python33....don't know if that makes any difference!

Comment: @user2031063 Version of python shouldn't matter. Your error message suggests that you've simply mixed up your `w` and `a` objects. Are you sure you have all your names right?

Comment: @Gjordis Exactly. For more detail, there's a link to the docs in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Help please

Comment: @user2031063 are you _sure_? Why does your error message say that the line `w.writerows(data)` is causing an error then? That line isn't in your example code. You do have a line `a.writerows(data)`. Your example code _should_ work as written.

Comment: Can you kindly run my code with 'wb' and see if it works.

Comment: Both @Aditya and I have confirmed that the code in your example (with `'w'` changed to `'wb'`) works correctly. You are definitely running something different than what you've written above.

Comment: sorry it is a.writerows(data) and not w.writerows(data). my code work as is and gives me blank lines..when I try 'wb' gives me the error message.

Comment: It is not running for me

Comment: this is the error I get >>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/CSV-test.py", line 7, in <module>
    a.writerows(data)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>>>

Comment: @Wilduck: it *does* matter which version of Python the OP is using, because of the 2/3 str/bytes changes.

Comment: @DSM Yep, I'm just realizing that. Definitely got mixed up by the docs. I'll try to clarify my answer in an edit.

Comment: Definitely accept DSM's answer. He knows what he's doing. @DSM Yep, I'm a little behind the times, both for this question and for my python version apparently. I learned something new today =).

Comment: @DSM...guide me please

Answer (score 15):

```
import csv

hello = [['Me','You'],['293', '219'],['13','15']]
length = len(hello[0])

with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    for y in range(length):
        csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in hello])
```

will produce an output like this

```
Me You
293 219
13 15
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank, but 'wb' gives me an error.

Comment: is this the same error you get? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Comment: does the solution help?

Comment: NO it didn't...I get this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/CSV-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = csv.write(b)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: copy what i have up directly, this works for me

Answer (score 5):

You need to open the file in binary `b` mode to take care of blank lines in Python 2. This isn't required in Python 3.

So, change `open('test.csv', 'w')` to `open('test.csv', 'wb')`.

Comment: I tried by I get this error: w.writrows(data) 'str' does not support the buffer interface. I am using python33..don't know if that makes any difference!!

Answer (score 3):

[Pyexcel](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) works great with both Python2 and Python3 without troubles.

Fast installation with pip:

```
pip install pyexcel
```

After that, only 3 lines of code and the job is done:

```
import pyexcel
data = [['Me', 'You'], ['293', '219'], ['54', '13']]
pyexcel.save_as(array = data, dest_file_name = 'csv_file_name.csv')
```