# missing values writing a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a csv file with python from a dictionnary which looks like follows:

```
1: [(3456,12),(4521,78)]
2: [(5478,45),(5609,43)]
3: [(8756,34),(6721,90)]
```

etc ...

I have several dictionaries like this. They can have until 30 keys. To write all the dictionnaries in a csv file, I wrote the following code which will be applied to each dictionnary:

```
for i,j in dictionnary.iteritems():
   for k in j:
     cr=csv.reader(open('/home/file.csv','rb'))
     datalist=list(cr)
     c=writerows(datalist+[[self.user_id, i,k[0],k[1]])
```

When I open the csv file, only a part of the dictionary is written. When I run multiple times the code, not the same entries of the dictionary are missing.
I don't understand what happens. Where could the problem come from?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693646/writing-to-csv-file-python

Comment: I thought I understood your problem, but I don't. Obviously, we're missing an essential part of your code. I don't understand why you **read** the same csv file on each iteration and the what the `writerows` function does. It cannot be the `csv.writer.writerows` as it's not attached to any object. See also the [example in the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer) on how to use the writer.

Comment: I think they're trying to append data to the end of the CSV. Which would explain why OP would need to refresh the `datalist` every loop

Comment: I read the csv file on each iteration because if I create the csv.writer before the iteration, i am said that the file is not open. The writerows function adds the content of my dictionnary at the end of what has already been written in the csv file. What is strange is that the code works, but only few items of my dictionnary are missing. And they are not the same at each run

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the file everytime you write to it. This means, you read the data twice. As others have suggested take the `csv.reader( open(...) )` part out of the loop. Also, I think you're trying to **append** data to the end of CSV. If that's what you're after, try using the `with` command and [opening the file](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in `ab` (append binary) mode:

```
with open('/home/file.csv','ab') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer( csvfile, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL )
    for i,j in dictionary.iteritems():
        for k in j:
            csvwriter.writerow( [ self.user_id, i, k[0], k[1] ] )
```

Comment: I obtain the following message:'expecting for a character buffer object'

Comment: I fixed a few things. I'm using a `csvwriter` and opening the file in `ab` which is append in binary. Check the edits.

Comment: Did it work? If it did, would you mind accepting an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will give you ideas about how to manage to complete a CSV file:

```
import csv
d1 = {1: [(3456,12),(4521,78)],
      2: [(5478,45),(5609,43)],
      3: [(8756,34),(6721,90)] }

d2 = {1: [(34,1),(4,7)],
      2: [(58,5),(56,4)],
      3: [(87,3),(67,9)] }

d3 = {1: [(111,22),(333,44)],
      3: [(1000,300),(2000,400)] }

d4 = {'AAA': [('arrze','iifuiyu')],
      'BBB': [(575757,'434343434')] }

def yi(input):
    for user_id,d in input:
        for i in d:
            for tu in d[i]:
                    yield [user_id, i, tu[0], tu[1]]

def csvcompl(fn,ds):           
    with open(fn,'ab') as cc:
        cr = csv.writer(cc)
        cr.writerows(yi(ds))

ds = (('Lavillenie',d1),('Abba',d2),(987654321,d3))
csvcompl('fifiroro.csv',ds)
csvcompl('fifiroro.csv',(('OPO',d4),))

with open('fifiroro.csv','r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

result

```
Lavillenie,1,3456,12
Lavillenie,1,4521,78
Lavillenie,2,5478,45
Lavillenie,2,5609,43
Lavillenie,3,8756,34
Lavillenie,3,6721,90
Abba,1,34,1
Abba,1,4,7
Abba,2,58,5
Abba,2,56,4
Abba,3,87,3
Abba,3,67,9
987654321,1,111,22
987654321,1,333,44
987654321,3,1000,300
987654321,3,2000,400
OPO,AAA,arrze,iifuiyu
OPO,BBB,575757,434343434
```