# Empty Rows In Between 2 rows in Python 2.6

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6 and I want to write in a csv file. This is my code.

```
fieldnames = ['Date', 'AICENT MO', 'AICENT MT', 'BELGACOM MO', 'BELGACOM MT', 'CITIC MO', 'CITIC MT', 'SYBASE MO','SYBASE MT']
csvfile = open('%s%s_%s.csv'%(report,module_name,lastMonth), 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
writer.writerow(fieldnames)
list = [date_file,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8]  
writer.writerow(list)
```

My Output is:

[image]

How to remove those empty rows?

Comment: You're not showing how you write the data rows - just the headers.

Comment: Ok @Raniz, I already added the data

Comment: That's not the code you're running. That only writes one row to the file. What data structure do you keep all your rows in and how do you print all the rows to the file?

Comment: Please provide the shortest **complete** program that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [Writing to CSV with Python adds blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693646/writing-to-csv-file-python)

The way you are opening the file is wrong.
You need to change your line `open('%s%s_%s.csv'%(report,module_name,lastMonth), 'w')` to `open('%s%s_%s.csv'%(report,module_name,lastMonth), 'wb')`. That is you should open the file as a binary file.

Comment: Hi @Vaulstein, I already changed to open('%s%s_%s.csv'%(report,module_name,lastMonth), 'wb') but the output is still the same.

Comment: Then the problem is with the list you are trying to write to the file.
I tried having the data in the format of a list within a list and the output file did not have any extra empty rows.

I would say you do something like:
hello = [['Me','You'],['293', '219'],['13','15']]
length = len(hello[0])


And then while writing do:

for y in range(length):
        csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in hello])