# Output from function to text/CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, beautifulsoup, output

I am counting the number of contractions in a certain set of presidential speeches, and want to output these contractions to a CSV or text file. Here's my code:

```
import urllib2,sys,os,csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
from string import punctuation as p
from multiprocessing import Pool
import re, nltk
import requests
import math, functools
import summarize
reload(sys)

def processURL_short(l):
    open_url = urllib2.urlopen(l).read()
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_url)
    item_div = item_soup.find('div',{'id':'transcript'},{'class':'displaytext'})
    item_str = item_div.text.lower()
    return item_str

every_link_test = ['http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427',
'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4424',
'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4453',
'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4612',
'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-5502']

data = {}
count = 0
for l in every_link_test:
    content_1 = processURL_short(l)
    for word in content_1.split():
        word = word.strip(p)
        if word in contractions:
            count = count + 1
        splitlink = l.split("/")
        president = splitlink[4]
        speech_num = splitlink[-1]
        filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president,speech_num)
    data[filename] = count
    print count, filename

   with open('contraction_counts.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
        a.writerows(data)
```

Running that `for` loop prints out

`79 obama_speech-4427
101 obama_speech-4424
101 obama_speech-4453
182 obama_speech-4612
224 obama_speech-5502`

I want to export that to a text file, where the numbers on the left are one column, and the president/speech number are in the second column. My `with` statement just writes each individual row to a separate file, which is definitely suboptimal.

Comment: If you google `write csv with python` you get plenty of answers, [try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693646/writing-to-csv-file-python)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. That output to CSV essentially put one letter in each column, and didn't even include the contraction count.

Comment: I would suggest editing this question or creating a new question regarding the code you tried to use to output the CSV - It's simpler for us to help you with the code you've already tried than for us to write you something from scratch.

Comment: The code I tried is at the tail end of the code above. It starts with `with open('contraction_counts.csv'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, this is a generic method, modify as you see fit

```
import csv
with open('somepath/file.txt', 'wb+') as outfile:
  w = csv.writer(outfile)
  w.writerow(['header1', 'header2'])
  for i in you_data_structure: # eg list or dictionary i'm assuming a list structure
    w.writerow([
      i[0],
      i[1],
    ])
```

or if a dictionary

```
import csv
with open('somepath/file.txt', 'wb+') as outfile:
  w = csv.writer(outfile)
  w.writerow(['header1', 'header2'])
  for k, v in your_dictionary.items(): # eg list or dictionary i'm assuming a list structure
    w.writerow([
      k,
      v,
    ])
```

Comment: I still get each letter of `filename` output to individual columns in 'contraction_counts.csv'... I'm trying to get one column for `counts` and another for `filename`.

Comment: Then you'll have to modify your data structure accordly, this snippet shows you how to do it, it's up to you to figure out how to use it. If I had a list of lists for example [[hi, hello], [by, bye]] this code would iterate over that list and I[0] would be hi on the first pass and by on the second pass.

Comment: Ok. It's actually saved as a dictionary (e.g. `{'washington_speech-3446': 8873,'washington_speech-3447': 8874, ...}`, so a bit of modification and I should be good, I suppose.

Comment: okay, added an example of how it would work with a dictionary.

Comment: okay. that definitely makes sense now, me being able to read the code for writing from a dictionary. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you open the output file inside the loop in `w` mode, meaning that it is erased on each iteration. You can easily solve it in 2 ways:

1. mode the `open` outside of the loop (normal way). You will open the file only once, add a line on each iteration and close it when exiting the `with` block:

   ```
   with open('contraction_counts.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
       a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
       for l in every_link_test:
           content_1 = processURL_short(l)
           for word in content_1.split():
               word = word.strip(p)
               if word in contractions:
                   count = count + 1
               splitlink = l.split("/")
               president = splitlink[4]
               speech_num = splitlink[-1]
               filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president,speech_num)
           data[filename] = count
           print count, filename
           a.writerows(data)
   ```
2. open the file in `a` (append) mode. On each iteration you reopen the file and write at the end instead of erasing it - this way uses more IO resources because of the open/close, and should be used only if the program can break and you want to be sure that all that was written before the crash has actually been saved to disk

   ```
   for l in every_link_test:
       content_1 = processURL_short(l)
       for word in content_1.split():
           word = word.strip(p)
           if word in contractions:
               count = count + 1
           splitlink = l.split("/")
           president = splitlink[4]
           speech_num = splitlink[-1]
           filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president,speech_num)
       data[filename] = count
       print count, filename

       with open('contraction_counts.csv','a',newline='') as fp:
           a = csv.writer(fp,delimiter = ',')
           a.writerows(data)
   ```

Comment: Both of those solutions leave me back where I started - with the output to `contraction_counts.csv` being each letter of `filename` in its own individual column, with no inclusion of the actual contradiction counts.