# Python: Exporting a list of lists to .CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

With the structure:

```
mylist = [ [a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h], .......[w,x,y,z]]
```

How can I export to a .csv file using each column and row like?  Is there useful functions to quickly format lists to .csv files this way?  I want each value in list to be a new tab in excel.

```
a   b   c   d
e   f   g   h
............
w   x   y   z
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to CSV with Python adds blank lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693646/writing-to-csv-with-python-adds-blank-lines)

Comment: `csv` files don't have tabs.

Comment: Look at the builtin-in csv module's docs. And csv files don't have tabs.

Comment: They can have tabs. c in `csv` doesn't always mean comma. It sometimes means "character"

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) explains writing CSV, and gives you an example in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
sep = "\t"

mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

with open('my.csv', 'w') as csv:
    for row in mylist:
        csv.write(sep.join(row))
        csv.write("\n")
```

Or the official [csv lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

`my.csv` is now :

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want.

```
csv_lines = []
for line in mylist:
    csv_lines.append(",".join(line))

f = open("mylist.csv", "w")
f.write("\n".join(csv_lines))
f.close()
```

The file `mylist.csv` should then be read correctly by excel automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is an efficient way of doing it if you list is not VERY huge

```
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(map(lambda x:x.join(", "), mylist).join("\n"))
```