# Python writing hex to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 and I want to be able to write hex to a file like this but i cannot get it to work. This gives me a TypeError and if encode it the output to the file isn't correct.

```
junk = '\x90' * 5
junk += '\xcc' * 5

fo = open("foo.list", "wb")

fo.write(junk)
fo.close()
```

this gives me a `type error, str doesn't support the buffer interface`, if i however do this

```
junk = '01BDF23A'
junk += '90' * 5
junk += 'cc' * 5


fo = open("foo3.m3u", "wb")
fo.write(binascii.unhexlify(junk))
fo.close()
```

it works but i would like to define them as hex (\x90), any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Post the error, please.

Comment: The error is presumably [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface), assuming that you replace `b` with `junk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, you must explicitly specify an encoding if you are trying to `write` a `str`. What you are trying to write are byte literals (see the [python 2 to 3 guide](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)), so change the code to actually use byte literals

```
junk = b'\x90' * 5
junk += b'\xcc' * 5

fo.write(junk)
```