# Python Reading From and Writing to Binary Files

Tags: file, python-3.x, binary

**The following is my question re-worded**

Reading the first 10 bytes of a binary file (operations later) -

```
infile = open('infile.jpg', 'rb')
outfile = open('outfile.jpg', 'wb')
x = infile.read(10)
for i in x:
    print(i, end=', ')
print(x)
outfile.write(bytes(x, "UTF-8"))
```

The first print statement gives -

```
255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70,
```

The second print statement gives -

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF'
```

a hexadecimal interpretation of the values in x.

```
outfile.write(bytes(x, "UTF-8"))
```

returns -

```
TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument
```

Then x must not be a normal string but rather a byte string, which is still iterable?

If I want to write the contents of x to outfile.jpg unaltered then I go -

```
outfile.write(x)
```

Now I try to take each x [i]  and perform some operation on each (shown below as a bone simple product of 1), assign the values to y and write y to outfile.jpg such that it is identical to infile.jpg.  So I try -

```
infile = open('infile.jpg', 'rb')
outfile = open('outfile.jpg', 'wb')
x = infile.read(10)

yi = len(x)
y = [0 for i in range(yi)]

j = 0
for i in x:
    y [j] = i*1
    j += 1

for i in x:
    print(i, end=', ')

print(x)

for i in y:
    print(i, end=', ')

print(y)

print(repr(x))
print(repr(y))

outfile.write(y)
```

The first print statement (iterating through x) gives -

```
255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70,
```

The second print statement gives -

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF'
```

The third print statement (iterating through y) gives -

```
255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70,
```

The print statement gives -

```
[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70]
```

And finally, printing repr(x) and repr(y), as suggested by Tim, gives, respectively -

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF'
[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70]
```

And the file write statement gives the error -

```
TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface
```

What I need is y to be the same type as x such that outfile.write(x) = outfile.write(y)

I stare into the eyes of the Python, but still I do not see its soul.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface seems that the String class changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Hunter - I replaced outfile.write(s) with outfile.write(s.encode('UTF-8') and received no errors!  However using infile.read() resulted in outfile.jpg being twice the size as infile.jpg and broken.  What I am trying to accomplish is read a  binary file, perform an operation, reverse that operation and write the ouput to a separate file such that they are identical.

Comment: The answer in the post I linked used `outfile.write(bytes(s, "UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 3):

They're not identical at all - they just *display* identically after `str()` is applied to them (which `print()` does implicitly).  Print the `repr()` of them and you'll see the difference.  Example:

```
>>> x = b'ab'
>>> y = "b'ab'"
>>> print(x)
b'ab'
>>> print(y) # displays identically
b'ab'
>>> print(repr(x)) # but x is really a 2-byte bytes object
b'ab'
>>> print(repr(y)) # and y is really a 5-character string
"b'ab'"
```

Mixing strings and bytes objects doesn't make sense (well, not in the absence of an explicit encoding - but you're not *trying* to encode/decode anything here, right?).  If you're working with binary files, then you shouldn't be using strings at all - you should be using `bytes` or `bytearray` objects.

So the problem isn't really in how you're writing:  the logic is fundamentally confused before then.

Can't guess what you want.  Please edit the question to show a complete, executable example of what you're *trying* to accomplish.  We don't need JPG files for this - make up some short, arbitrary binary data.  Like:

```
dummy_jpg = b'\x01\x02\xff'
```

Comment: Wow, repr() shows there is a difference.  I will have to rethink the logic of what I am try to do.

Answer (score 1):

**... and this is how you you read and write to files in Python in binary mode.**

```
#open binary files infile and outfile
infile = open('infile.jpg', 'rb')
outfile = open('outfile.jpg', 'wb')

#n = bytes to read
n=5

#read bytes of infile to x
x = infile.read(n)

#print x type, x
print()
print('x = ', repr(x), type(x))
print()
```

x =  b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00' class 'bytes'

```
#define y of type list, lenth xi, type list
xi = len(x)
y = [0 for i in range(xi)]

#print y type, y
print('y =', repr(y), type(y))
print()
```

y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] class 'list'

```
#convert x to 8 bit octals and place in y, type list
j=0
for i in x:
    y [j] = '{:08b}' .format(ord(i))
    j += 1

#print y type, and y
print('y =', repr(y), type(y))
print()
```

y = ['11111111', '11011000', '11111111', '11100000', '00000000'] class 'list'

```
#perform bit level operations on y [i], not done in this example.

#convert y [i] back to integer
j=0
for i in y:
    y [j] = int(i, 2)
    j += 1

#print y type, and y
print('y =', repr(y), type(y))
print()
```

y = [255, 216, 255, 224, 0] class 'list'

```
#convert y to type byte and place in z
z = bytearray(y)

#print z type, and z
print('z =', repr(z), type(z))
print()
```

z = bytearray(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00') class 'bytearray'

```
#output z to outfile
outfile.write(z)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
outfile = open('outfile.jpg', 'rb')

#read bytes of outfile to x
x = outfile.read(n)

#print x type, and x
print('x =', repr(x), type(x))
print()
```

x = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00' class 'bytes'

```
#conclusion:  first n bytes of infile = n bytes of outfile (without bit level operations)

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying!  What you want is very easy, but you really need to read the docs for the `bytes` and `bytearray` types.  What you **DO NOT** want is anything having to do with:

- Unicode
- strings
- encoding
- decoding

Those are all utterly irrelevant here.  You have binary data from start to finish, and need to stick to `bytes` and/or `bytearray` objects.  Both are sequences of bytes ("little integers" in `range(256)`); `bytes` is an immutable sequence, and `bytearray` is a mutable sequence.

> Then x must not be a normal string but rather a byte string, which is still iterable?

Read the docs ;-)  `x` is not "a string"; do this to see its type:

```
print(type(x))
```

That will display:

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

It's a `bytes` object, as briefly explained already.  It's a sequence, so yes, it's iterable, like all sequences.  You can also index into it, slice it, etc.

Your `y` is a list.  Alas, I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish with it.

> What I need is y to be the same type as x such that outfile.write(x) = outfile.write(y)

No, you do not need `x` and `y` to be the same type.  You *do* want to be able to write `y` as binary data.  For that you need to create a `bytes` **or** `bytearray` object.  That's very easy; just do one of these:

```
 y = bytes(y)
```

or

```
 y = bytearray(y)
```

Then

```
outfile.write(y)
```

will do what you want.

Although, as above, I have no idea why you created a list here to begin with.  A much easier way to create the same list would have been to skip all the loops and just write:

```
 y = list(x)
```

If I'm getting through, you should be starting to suspect that your mental model of what's going on here is too *complicated*, not too simple.  You're imagining difficulties that don't really exist :-)  Reading from a binary file gives you a `bytes` object (or see the file `.readinto()` method if you want reading a binary file to fill a `bytearray` object instead), while writing to a binary file requires giving it a `bytes` or `bytearray` object to write.  That's all there is to it.