# 'str' does not support the buffer interface Python3 from Python2

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, arrays

Hi have this two funtions in Py2 works fine but it doesn´t works on Py3

```
def encoding(text, codes):
    binary = ''
    f = open('bytes.bin', 'wb')
    for c in text:
        binary += codes[c]
    f.write('%s' % binary)
    print('Text in binary:', binary)
    f.close()
    return len(binary)

def decoding(codes, large):
    f = file('bytes.bin', 'rb')
    bits = f.read(large)
    tmp = ''
    decode_text = ''
    for bit in bits:
        tmp += bit
        if tmp in fordecodes:
            decode_text += fordecodes[tmp]
            tmp = ''
    f.close()
    return decode_text
```

The console ouputs this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Practica2.py", line 83, in <module>
    large = encoding(text, codes)
  File "Practica2.py", line 56, in encoding
    f.write('%s' % binary)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: you need to cast to  `bytes` or open in "wt" mode if using python 3.4

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `'w'` is enough.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files - note changes from 2.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Answer (score 21):

The fix was simple for me

Use

```
f = open('bytes.bin', 'w')
```

instead of

```
f = open('bytes.bin', 'wb')
```

In python 3 `'w'` is what you need, not `'wb'`.

Answer (score 13):

In Python 2, bare literal strings (e.g. `'string'`) are *bytes*, whereas in Python 3 they are *unicode*. This means if you want literal strings to be treated as bytes in Python 3, you always have to explicitly mark them as such.

So, for instance, the first few lines of the `encoding` function should look like this:

```
binary = b''
f = open('bytes.bin', 'wb')
for c in text:
    binary += codes[c]
f.write(b'%s' % binary)
```

and there are a few lines in the other function which need similar treatment.

See [Porting to Python 3](http://python3porting.com/bookindex.html), and the section [Bytes, Strings and Unicode](http://python3porting.com/problems.html#bytes-strings-and-unicode) for more details.