# Python 3 - Open and Save files full contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, openfiledialog, temporary-files, savefiledialog

I am trying to open a file using 'askopenfilename' and then save the contents of that file to a new file. i could then open that new file for amendment. However I am getting errors and when I attempt to do so. Any help appreciated.

```
def startapp(self):
    self.grid()

    filebutton = tkinter.Button(self, text="Open File for Selection button", command=self.getfile)
    filebutton.grid(column=1, row=0)

    quitbutton = tkinter.Button(self, text="Quit", command=quit)
    quitbutton.grid(column=2, row=0)

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

def getfile(self):   #this is the open file function

    selectedfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('All files', '*.*')])
    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    temp.write(selectedfile)
```

The errors provided:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/**/PycharmProjects/FileAnalyser/FileAnalyser1/GUI/ParentWindow.py", line 31, in getfile
temp.write(selectedfile)
File "C:\Python34\lib\tempfile.py", line 399, in func_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write text (strings) to this file. If so, you'll need to specify a non-binary mode when creating the `TemporaryFile` by changing

```
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
```

to

```
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w')
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945613/str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface-python3-from-python2) for more details and the [tempfile docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) for the fact that it defaults to expecting bytes, not strings.