# Strings operation issue while switching from python 2.x to python 3

Tags: python, ctype

I am facing some problem with strings switching from python 2.x to python 3

Issue 1:

```
from ctypes import*
charBuffer=create_string_buffer(1000)
var = charBuffer.value  # var contains like this "abc:def:ghi:1234"
a,b,c,d= var.split(':')
```

It works fine in python 2.x but not in 3.x it is throwing some errors like this 
a,b,c,d= var.split(':')
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

I got the links after doing some research in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945613/str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface-python3-from-python2)

If I print, desired output would be

```
a= abc
b =def
c=ghi 
d=1234
```

Issue2:

```
from ctypes import*
cdll = "Windll"
var = 0x1fffffffffffffffffffffff # I want to send this long variable to character pointer which is in cdll

charBuf =create_string_buffer(var.to_bytes(32,'little'))
cdll.createBuff (charBuf )

cdll function
int createBuff (char * charBuff){
   print charBuff
   return 0;
}
```

I want to send this long variable to character pointer which is in cdll, since its a character pointer its throwing errors.
Need your valuable inputs on how could I achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Vineet Kumar Doshi, added the desired output in my problem statement

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.x , '.value' on return of create_string_buffer() returns a byte string .

In your example you are trying to split the byte string using a Unicode string (which is the normal string in Python 3.x ) . This is what is causing your issue.

You would need to either split with byte string . Example -

```
a,b,c,d = var.split(b':')
```

Or you can decode the byte string to a Unicode string using '.decode()' method on it .

Example -

```
var = var.decode('<encoding>')
```

Comment: I would discourage the second example. Splitting a unicode string with a byte string is asymmetric. That is, it works on py2, but not py3. eg. `u"a b".split(b" ")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked!! I have added the clear goal for problem statement, could you please check.

Comment: True , but I was just giving that option of var or other variables were needed as normal string (and not byte string) afterwards. If it is only required for sending to c function , then the first is the recommended approach

Comment: @ Anand S Kumar, I am facing some issue in sending 128 nit Long integer to character pointer in cdll, completely stuck with this.could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Split using `b":"` and you will be fine in both versions of python.

In py2 `str` is a bytestring, in py3 `str` is a unicode object. The object returned by the ctypes string buffer is a bytestring (`str` on py2 and `bytes` on py3). By writing the string literal as `b"...` you force it to be a bytestring in both version of python.

Comment: That's great!! it worked, I have added the clear goal for problem statement, could you please check.

Comment: @ Dunes  in issue2 facing some problem in sending 128 nit Long integer to character pointer in cdll, how can I compatible with python, could you please help?