# Any ideas how to fix TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting this error "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface" Not sure what is going wrong. Any assistance would be great.

```
import zlib
#User input for sentnce & compression.
sentence = input("Enter the text you want to compress: ")
com = zlib.compress(sentence)
#Opening file to compress user input.
with open("listofwords.txt", "wb") as myfile:
    myfile.write(com)
```

Comment: this post can help you with your problem ['str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945613/str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface-python3-from-python2) :)

Comment: make your unicode string a bytes object instead

Comment: use `zlib.compress(sentence.encode('utf-8'))` (if you like utf-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to pass `str` object (Unicode text) instead of binary data (byte sequence):

```
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.compress('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Python 3.5 improves the error message here:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.compress('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

To save text as binary data, you could encode it using a character encoding. To compress the data, you could use `gzip` module:

```
import gzip
import io

with io.TextIOWrapper(gzip.open('sentence.txt.gz', 'wb'),
                      encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print(sentence, file=file)
```