# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface 3 4

Tags: python

```
  # Send data
    print (sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
    sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)
```

I have this above error at this sentence
sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address).

Comment: provide the error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/1.py", line 14, in <module>
    sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `str` is `unicode` since Python 3.0, you need to `encode` your `str`'s before using it as a byte stream:

```
sent = sock.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), server_address)
```