# Python + Create csv file on Windows

Tags: python, csv

I want to create the csv file - output.csv

I run this python code ( version 3.4.3 ) from my Visual studio 10

```
import csv
RESULT = ['linux','solaris','unix','aix','win']
resultFile = open("output.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
wr.writerow(RESULT)
```

but from unclear reason I get this errors

```
 TypeError Occurred
 'str' dose not support the buffer interface
```

this error is after the **wr.writerow(RESULT)** line ( with red sign )

what its wrong here

- remark - I must to say - when I write the wr. ( the last line ) then after the dot "." I not see auto completion

Comment: related question> [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface) (possible duplicate ?)

Comment: Is there a reason for writing in binary format? `'wb'` instead of `'w'`.

Comment: well - when I remove the "b" its created the csv but its empty !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way you write your result:

```py
wr.writerow(bytes(RESULT, 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: is it because sometning that related to modules , or maybe need to install some modules ?