# Python 3 bytes vs strings

Tags: python

This may be a duplicate but I can't solve my problem.
This line gives me the error

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>   .

```
unescaped = html.replace(r'\""', '"')
```

Does it mean I have to write

```
unescaped = html.replace(bytes(r'\""', 'UTF-8'), bytes('"', 'UTF-8'))
```

Each time I need to replace a string?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Comment: Where do you get the html from (and what encoding is it)? I would guess that you should decode the html, then replace (or do whatever you want with the html) and at the end, if you need it, encode it back to what encoding you need it to be.

Comment: @GolezTrol: there surely are better dupes than that. This is about literal values, not string data read from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using *literal values* so just use a `bytes` literal string, with a `b` prefix:

```
unescaped = html.replace(rb'\""', b'"')
```