# Getting error when using split()

Tags: python, csv

I have a file that's poorly formatted, if I try to open it with simply `open('data.csv', 'r')` I get :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in 
    position 4681: character maps to <undefined>
```

So I used `open('data.csv', 'rb')` instead and it works fine. Then I tried to transfer the needed information to a new file without success using:

```
with open('datacsv', 'rb') as file, open('new.csv', 'w') as newf:
    for f in file:
        newf.write(str(f.split(',')[0:5]))
```

If I take off the `split()` it writes the data to the new file fine, but if I add the split which I'm using to extract first few columns I get:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I tried the suggestions in here [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface?rq=1) but none of them help.

How else can I prevent the `TypeError` from rising?

Comment: What version of python are you using? Can you try python3, with r, not rb.

Comment: It is python3, if I do without 'rb' the file won't open at all.

Comment: That is your problem, not the type error. You need to figure out what the encoding of the file is and then pass the encoding on open, like so `open(filename, encoding="utf8")`. changing to rb simply masks your root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is failing to decode with the default encoding. You should find out how the file is encoded and then pass that encoding as a named parameter to `open`. An easy way to check the encoding is to open the file in a decent text editor such as Notepad++, Sublime, BBEdit, etc. The editor will make a reasonable effort to detect the encoding.

Comment: I thought I did try `open('datacsv', 'r',encoding='utf8')` but I guess I overlooked it. That fixed the problem.