# How to capture interlaced stdin and stdout from a Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write a Python script that automatically grades a Python script submitted by a student, where the student's script uses the `input()` function to get some information from the user.

Suppose the student's script is something simple like this:

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
print(f'Hello {name}!')
```

The portion of the test script that runs the student script is something like this:

```
import subprocess

run_cmd = 'python student_script.py'
test_input = 'Bob'

p = subprocess.run(run_cmd.split(), input=test_input, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

After running that portion of the test script, output from the student's script is captured and can be accessed via `p.stdout` which is a string having this value:

```
'Enter your name: Hello Bob!\n'
```

No surprise there, since this is everything output by the student script, but notice that the 'Bob' test input is not included.

In the test report, I want to show the script input and output in the same way that it would appear if the script had been run from a command line, which would look like this:

```
Enter your name: Bob
Hello Bob!
```

Given that the scripts are written by students, the prompt message output by the student script could be anything (e.g., What is your name?, Who are you?, Type in name:, etc.) and the student script might also print something other than 'Hello Bob!', so I don't think there is any way to reliably figure out where to correctly insert the 'Bob' test input (and a trailing new line) into `p.stdout`.

Is there a way to get `subprocess.run()` to capture interlaced stdin and stdout?

Or is there another way to run a Python script from a Python script that captures interlaced stdin and stdout?

Ideally, for this example, I would be able to get a string having this value:

```
'Enter your name: Bob\nHello Bob!\n'
```

I've search SO and read through the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), but thus far I've come up short on finding a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Subprocess .run has a stdout *and* a stderr file handle args. Have you tried setting both to same file you provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. I expect there is a more elegant way to do it, but it works on the Ubuntu Linux computer that the automated test scripts run on. I have not tried it on Windows, but I believe it will not work since `os.set_blocking()` is only supported on Unix per the [os module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.set_blocking).

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

run_cmd = 'python student_script.py'
test_input = 'Bob'

# Start the student script running
p = subprocess.Popen(run_cmd.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text = True)

# Give the script some time to run
time.sleep(2)

# String to hold interleaved stdin and stdout text
stdio_text = ''

# Capture everything from stdout
os.set_blocking(p.stdout.fileno(), False)  # Prevents readline() blocking
stdout_text = p.stdout.readline()
while stdout_text != '':
    stdio_text += stdout_text
    stdout_text = p.stdout.readline()

# Append test input to interleaved stdin and stdout text
stdio_text += (test_input + '\n')

try:
    # Send test input to stdin and wait for student script to terminate
    stdio_text += p.communicate(input=test_input, timeout=5)[0]
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # Something is wrong with student script
    pass

p.terminate()
```

The key to this solution working is `os.set_blocking()`, which I found out about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291466/20004315).  Without it `readline()` blocks indefinitely.

I don't love the `time.sleep(2)` since it assumes it will take 2 seconds or less for the student script to reach the point where it calls `input()`, but there does not seem to be any way to determine when a process is looking for input from stdin. The sleep time could be increased for longer scripts.

If you've got any ideas for improvements, please share.

Comment: relevent on windows [Supplying input in subprocess and print the inputs along with the outputs (Python running Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73763291/supplying-input-in-subprocess-and-print-the-inputs-along-with-the-outputs-pytho/73763539#73763539)