# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface when using flask sendmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sendmail

I'm attempting to use sendmail within flask to send some emails - but the error message coming back are a bit cryptic.

```
from flask.ext.sendmail import Message
from flask.ext.sendmail import Mail

mail = Mail()
mail.init_app(app)
msg = Message("Hello".encode('utf-8'), sender="xxx@xxx.com".encode('utf-8'), recipients="xxx@xxx.com".encode('utf-8'))
msg.body = "testing"
msg.html = "testing"
mail.send(msg)
```

The problem appears at mail.send(msg). Here is the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/login.py", line 129, in registersub
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_sendmail/mail.py", line 40, in send
    message.send(self.connect())
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_sendmail/message.py", line 115, in send
    if self.is_bad_headers():
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_sendmail/message.py", line 72, in is_bad_headers
    if c in val:
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Where is the likely culprit?

Comment: Could it have something to do with `msg.body` and `msg.html` not being encoded with `utf-8`?

Comment: Could possibly uncrypt error message for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Comment: @MorganThrapp I've encoded msg.body and msg.html, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Could you please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example

```
>>> 'c' in b'val'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

It's the same error you've got, so don't encode the `str` values you're using.

Comment: I've removed encoding from message, but still get an issue, only in a different part of the trace now.

Comment: @Navonod If it's not this TypeError anymore, it might be a completely new question you could ask; just leave a link here.