# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface-Python

Tags: python

What I am doing wrong here?

It says:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('areas.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(b'CONTOUR VALUES x AREAS\n')
    f.write(b'2\n')
    for k in range(-40, 41, 1):
        flag = 0.0
        for i in range(NY):
            for j in range(NX):
                if values[i,j] > k:
                    flag = flag + 1.0
        f.write(str(k)+' '+str( ((NX*NY) - flag ) * cell_area)+'\n')
plt.show()
```

Comment: related: [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5471158/4279)

Comment: `f.write(str(k)+' '+str( ((NX*NY) - flag ) * cell_area)+'\n')` these not bytes.

Comment: how to fix that line then? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you open the file in binary mode (`'wb'`)? Unrelated: use [`print()` function instead of `f.write()` for *text* streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: @Sally7874 Try `text = str(k)+' '+str( ((NX*NY) - flag ) * cell_area)+'\n' ; f.write(bytes(text.encode('utf8')))`.

Comment: @KevinGuan: OP probably wants `'w'` mode here (and therefore remove `b''`). Also, `bytes()` around `text.encode('utf-8')` is redundant redundant.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, because I don't know why does OP use `'wb'` mode...However, on Python 3 if without `.encode('utf-8')`, it'll raise `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`.