# Python append to csv file without white rows and without repeating columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

hi I have some problem.

```
import csv
test = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for t in test:
    with open('names.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

        fieldnames = ['acol', 'bcol', 'ccol']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'acol': t, 'bcol': t, 'ccol': t})
```

'names.csv' result

acol    bcol    ccol

a   a   a

acol    bcol    ccol

b   b   b

acol    bcol    ccol

c   c   c

acol    bcol    ccol

d   d   d

acol    bcol    ccol

e   e   e''

there is whiteline and colume repeat
i want result without white rows and without colume repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
import csv
test = ['a','b','c','d','e']

with open('names.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['acol', 'bcol', 'ccol']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for t in test:
        writer.writerow({'acol': t, 'bcol': t, 'ccol': t})
```

Comment: but... there is whiteline still

Comment: the whiteline is probably an issue of importing it back. I do not see a whiteline if I reopen the file in e.g LibreOffice.

Comment: The white line doesn't seem to appear for me.

Comment: mistake,,, not whiteline   ---> white rows

Comment: Replace this line `with open('names.csv', 'a') as csvfile:` to `with open('names.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: i use ('names.csv', 'wb')  this is error ``Traceback (most recent call last):

    self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>>> ``

Comment: i use exel2007 version..and  python3.4

Comment: For python 3.4 you need to encode the string before writing in to a file. checkout this link for python 3x string encoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
test = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for i,t in enumerate(test):
    with open('names.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

        fieldnames = ['acol', 'bcol', 'ccol']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if i == 0:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'acol': t, 'bcol': t, 'ccol': t})
```

The other solution provided by Divakar is more elgant and faster since you do not open the file in every loop.

Comment: I do not see whitelines in my output

Comment: No, there are none. Can you post how you open it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
import csv
test = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for t in test:
    with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:

        fieldnames = ['acol', 'bcol', 'ccol']
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)

        for elem in test:
            writer.writerow(elem * 3)
```

here is my output from `names.csv` it dosen't have any newline

```
acol,bcol,ccol
a,a,a
b,b,b
c,c,c
d,d,d
e,e,e
```

Comment: what do you mean by whiterows, i don't see any empty lines in my output

Comment: i've pasted my output

Comment: <code>acol,bcol,ccol\n
a,a,a\n
b,b,b\n
c,c,c\n
d,d,d\n
e,e,e</code>

Comment: [code]acol,bcol,ccol\n a,a,a\n b,b,b\n c,c,c\n d,d,d\n e,e,e[/code]

Comment: use `` `acol,bcol,ccol\n a,a,a\n b,b,b\n c,c,c\n d,d,d\n e,e,e`

Comment: use `` acol,bcol,ccol\n a,a,a\n b,b,b\n c,c,c\n d,d,d\n e,e,e

Comment: ``acol,bcol,ccol
a,a,a
b,b,b
c,c,c
d,d,d
e,e,e``

Comment: you have enter line , why can't i?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
test = ['a','b','c','d','e']

with open('names.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['acol', 'bcol', 'ccol']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,delimiter=' ',fieldnames=fieldnames,lineterminator=' ')
    writer.writeheader()
    for t in test:
        writer.writerow({'acol': t, 'bcol': t, 'ccol': t})
```

you are writing headers inside the loop so they are rewritten many times,by default line terminator is '\n' which gives new white space at end of line.This gives the result you cited above

Comment: what do you mean?@DOMIDOMI i checked the question before it was edited,i thought the results posted before were what you wanted to accomplish,have you checked the lineterminator option?

Comment: acol bcol ccol

a a a

acol bcol ccol

b b b

acol bcol ccol

c c c

acol bcol ccol

d d d

acol bcol ccol

e e e

Comment: i understand...but did you add those modification.i mean copy and paste those code exactly...because i get different result here