# How to decompress a file using python 3.x and gzip

Tags: python, gzip, zlib, compression

I have had help creating a piece of code that compresses a input from a user.The code then transfers this compressed version into a file. The code also sends the input into a file to see how much the file has been compressed.

```
import gzip, time

plaintext = input("Please enter the text you want to compress: ")
file_ = open('text.txt', 'w')
file_.write(str(plaintext))
file_.close()
with gzip.open('compressed_file.text' + ".gz", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(bytes(plaintext, 'UTF-8'))


with open("data.txt","wb") as fh:
    with open('compressed_file.text.gz', 'rb') as fd:
        fh.write(fd.read())
```

I want some help on how to decompress the file to make the original user input.

Comment: What's giving you trouble?  It seems to be a pretty simple problem given the utilities in the `gzip` module...

Comment: I want to decompress what i have compressed. But i don't know how and would like some assistance. The second piece of code only sends the compressed sentence back to the user, it don't make the original sentence which is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I think, just reading GZIP file and writing back to file will help you.

```
import gzip

plaintext = input("Please enter the text you want to compress: ")

with open("text.txt","wb") as file_:
    file_.write(str(plaintext.encode('utf-8')))

filename = input("Please enter the desired filename: ")
print("Name of file to be zipped is text.txt")
print("Name of GZIP file is ",filename+'.gz')
print("Zipping file...")
with gzip.GzipFile(filename + ".gz", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(open("text.txt").read())

print("Name of unzipped file is unzip_text.txt")
print("Unzipping ...")
with gzip.GzipFile(filename + ".gz", 'rb') as inF:
    with file("unzip_text.txt", 'wb') as outF:
        s = inF.read()
        outF.write(s.encode('utf-8'))

print("Content of unzip file is...")
with open("unzip_text.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        print line
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python gz.py
Please enter the text you want to compress: "My name is Dinesh"
Please enter the desired filename: "dinesh"
Name of file to be zipped is text.txt
('Name of GZIP file is ', 'dinesh.gz')
Zipping file...
Name of unzipped file is unzip_text.txt
Unzipping ...
Content of unzip file is...
My name is Dinesh

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\GCSE WORK\Computing\A 4.5.3\Coursework\Task 3\Task 3.py", line 13, in <module>
    with gzip.open('text.txt.gz', 'rb') as fd:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\gzip.py", line 52, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\gzip.py", line 184, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt.gz'
>>>

Comment: Replace "text.txt.gz" by the GZIP file name you code is creating above

Comment: I have but it comes out saying that "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'comp2'" comp2 is the file name.

Comment: I altered the code and it did not give me the decompressed file, it gave me the compressed file back

Comment: Your bit of code simply returns the compressed file, it does not decompress it to make the original input.

Comment: it comes up with error TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: i am using python 3.3.3

Comment: Gotcha... Just add encode('utf-8'). Please check updated code.

Comment: file_.write(str(plaintext.encode('utf-8')))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: I have changed the code so it removes the str from the top part of the code. Please check the code Know. But i still get an error message(self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffff
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer as [I found it on the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471351/6879826).

```
plaintext = input('Please enter some text')
filename = 'foo.gz'
with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(bytes(plaintext, 'UTF-8'))
with gzip.open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    outfile_content = infile.read().decode('UTF-8')
print(outfile_content)
```

This compresses the input, stores it in the a file and also decompress the file to make the original input. This decompressed input is then printed to the shell.