# How to fix the error = 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, csv

I'm developing a Python script to download a .csv file for data from a set of pumps via IP. However, there is an error in the passage >> lines = download.content.split ("\ n") << that I can not understand. In the end, I want to break the list and grab the first 4 rows of data from the first 2 columns (time and pump1).

```
import requests

url = "http://10.0.4.49/get.cgi?menu=download_logvalues"
local_output_file = "B51.csv"

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ("admin", "admin")
download = s.get(url)
lines = download.content.split("\n")

time = []  # Initially empty time stamp.
pump1 = [] # Pump 1 data (column B of the .csv file)

i=4 # Reading data only, excluding the header - beginning from the 4th line
while (i<=8):
    time.append(lines[i].split(";")[0])
    pump1.append(lines[i].split(";")[1])
i += 1

print (time)
print(pump1)


>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\teste 0802.py", line 14, in <module>
  lines = download.content.split("\n")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>>>
```

[Data B51_csv.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFdWh.jpg)

Comment: Did you search?  This was [answered _six years ago!_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Comment: download.content.decode('utf-8')

Comment: @HaifengZhang: Please don't answer in comments. If you were wrong, we would not be able to downvote your suggestion.