# Python3: File <stdin> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, subprocess

I know similar problems have been asked many times, but I don't think they solved my mine.

I'm basically trying to convert the following bash command into python using the `subprocess` module:

```sh
cat <a python file> | ssh <ip> python - <args>
```

Here's what I have:

```py
with open('<the python file>', 'r') as python_file:
    print(subprocess.check_output(['ssh', '<ip>', 'python - <args>', ], stdin=python_file))
```

And I'm running the above code from my local laptop using python3. When on the *target* machine (the remote server with `<ip>`) the python version is 2.7, this code snippet works fine. But if I switch the python version of the *target* machine to 3.4, I got the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 114, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 94, in main
File "<stdin>", line 22, in load
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I've tried the following:

1. open the python file with in binary mode: `open('<a python file'>, 'rb')`
2. change the subprocess args from `['ssh', '<ip>', 'python - <args>']` to `['ssh', '<ip>', 'python', '-', '<args>']`.

But none of them worked. Can anyone give some suggestions? Thanks!

**[Update]**

Thanks to @Justin Ezequiel 's comment, this turned out to be a problem of `'<the python file>'` instead of the code snippet above. In `'<the python file>'` there is the following code:

```py
columns = ['KNAME', 'TYPE', 'SIZE', 'MOUNTPOINT']  # (1)
lsblk_args = ['lsblk', '-i', '-n', '-o', ','.join(columns)]  # (2)
output = subprocess.check_output(lsblk_args).strip()  # (3)
parsed_res = _parse(output.split('\n'), columns)  # (4)
```

And if I change the (3) line to

```py
output = subprocess.check_output(lsblk_args).decode('utf-8').strip()
```

Everything works just fine.

Comment: Check out the recommendations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks! But I've checked out this question before. My problem is that I don't explicitly write to a file. And even if I tried to open the file in binary mode, i.e. in bytes, it still didn't work. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Well without seeing the contents of `'<the python file>'` we can only guess at what could be causing your error.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't realize this is actually because of the contents in `'<the python file>'`. I've figured out the problem and updated the post. Thanks again!