# Compress/Decompress a String in Python 3

Tags: python, gzip, zlib

This question is tacked several times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839323/compress-a-string-in-python-3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243119/how-to-compress-or-compact-a-string-in-python) but not answered completely. As decompression doesn't yield the original string.

```
>>> s = "some string to test zlib"
>>> z = zlib.compress(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> z = zlib.compress(s.encode("utf8"))
>>> y = zlib.decompress(z)
>>> y
b'some string to test zlib'
>>> print (s, y)
some string to test zlib b'some string to test zlib'
```

So decompression returns the original string included in "b''"

```
>>> p = str(y)
>>> p
"b'some string to test zlib'"
```

The same behavior by the way with gzip.

Answer (score 2):

`y.decode('utf-8')` - the b is just an indication that this is a `bytes` type being printed:

```
s = "some string to test zlib"
z = zlib.compress(s.encode("utf-8"))
y = zlib.decompress(z)
y
print (s, y)
print (s, y.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
some string to test zlib b'some string to test zlib'
some string to test zlib some string to test zlib
```